# C# OOP Syntax Query

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get spun up on C#, so excuse this rudimentary question.

In the following code, I do not understand this statement `var eventData = (StorageBlobCreatedEventData)eventGridEvent.Data;` Obviously, it's creating a variable named `eventData` of type `StorageBlobCreatedEventData`, but why are there parentheses around the class?

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("EventGridTrigger")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# Event Grid trigger handling EventGrid Events");
            log.LogInformation($"New event received: {eventGridEvent.Data}");

            if (eventGridEvent.Data is StorageBlobCreatedEventData)
            {
                var eventData = (StorageBlobCreatedEventData)eventGridEvent.Data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is Boxing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) -- as casting it to a specific type

Comment: var someDoubleNumber = (double)1;  Same principle. It is casting something to something. In my example, casting integer to double. In your probably some arbitrary object to specific data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I understand it now. thanks so much.

Comment: Side note: please don't use advice by @TryingToImprove in your conversations with others as that conversion is either un-boxing (if `StorageBlobCreatedEventData` is value type and `.Data` is `object`) or just regular cast (if `StorageBlobCreatedEventData` is reference type). The link their provided does explain meaning of the "boxing" word and makes it clear that it does not apply to conversion from `object` (assuming `EventGridEvent.Data` which is of type `object`)

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis in that context is an object cast.  The type it is passed in is a more generic type.  The `if(event.Data is StorageBlob...` detects that it is of a more specific type, and if so then inside the if we know we can successfully cast it to that type.  Now this example doesn't actually do anything with that variable, so a little nonsensical, but usually you'd then be able to do things like `eventData.SomeMethodOnlyAvailableOnStorageBlob()`.  I.e. access properties and methods that are only declared on the specific StorageBlobCreatedEventData type which aren't available on the more generic type.

Generally it is unsafe to cast from a generic type to a more specific type.  You need to perform a check first to ensure that it is the specific type before attempting the cast.

This is basically a feature detection pattern.  If you see that a type implements a specific derived class or interface, then conditionally do something with that.

Answer (score 0):

The code `(StorageBlobCreatedEventData)` is an explicit cast.

So sometimes the compiler can't explicitly know which class you expect, so you need to tell it in this way.  Or sometimes you might want to cast a child to a parent.

Taking the examples from the MS documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

```
// Create a new derived type.
Giraffe g = new Giraffe();

// Implicit conversion to base type is safe.
Animal a = g;

// Explicit conversion is required to cast back
// to derived type. Note: This will compile but will
// throw an exception at run time if the right-side
// object is not in fact a Giraffe.
Giraffe g2 = (Giraffe)a;
```